# Is this Singleton + Lazy Loading?

Tags: c#, session, design-patterns, singleton, lazy-loading

```
public class UserSession
{
   private UserSession()
   {
   }

   public static UserSession Current
   {
       get
       {
           var session= (UserSession)HttpContext.Current.Session["_userSession"];
           if (session == null)
           {
               session = new UserSession();
               HttpContext.Current.Session["_userSession"] = session;
           }
           return session;
       }
   }

   public User User { get; set; }
}

//USAGE
UserSession.Current.User
```

I'm trying to figure out what patterns are used in this code. 
My understanding is that this is a

1. Singleton Pattern (in fact there is a private constructor) and a
2. Lazy Loading (or lazy initialization?) because the way the GET is implemented.

I'm also confused by the

3. UserSession property which is the same type of the class and the usage itself seems weird to me.

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: *"Can someone explain what is happening here?"* The `static UserSession` (read-only) property returns the `HttpContext.Current.Session["_userSession"]`, and instantiates it first if it's `null`. Apparently it stores an object of type `UserSession`.

Comment: Yes.  If the User Session doesn't exist in session, it gets created and stuck in there.  However, think about what happens if two threads start executing this code simultaneously, particularly the null check - they will each create a new UserSession object and return two different ones.  The typical singleton like this includes a lock and two null checks.  You can get around that by using `Lazy<T>`, which handles all the plumbing for you.

Comment: I would argue it can't be properly singleton because it isn't threadsafe. Double lock pattern may or may not be safe. It depends on your CPU architecture and how it flushes its cache line and is well beyond my pay grade. Just use Lazy<T>. If you do go with locks, just forgo the null check outside the lock or get very familiar with each architecture your target.

Answer (score 0):

Here I see singleton pattern:
static method of a class generates class instance if it doesn't exist

As for LazyLoading, I'm not sure we could see like that, because the idea of lazy loading is to save resources but here we can see a lightweight object

using static method of the class for getting the instance of the same class is a common practice but not the best approach. The better alternative is using context to get instances of classes and avoid using static methods because it could be called from anywhere of the app but here we are facing HttpContext.Current static property which is in my mind a design issue itself so we could be using UserContext like that